# Button click is triggering form action from form not the formaction from button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
 <form id="form1" asp-controller="AccPay" asp-action="SavePay" asp-route- 
 redirect=@ViewBag.redirectPath>


<button type="submit" id="accept" value="Accept"  formaction="/AccPay/AcceptPay?redirect=@ViewBag.redirectPath" 
onclick="return checkDateValidation1('@ViewBag.redirectPath')">
     Accept<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right padding-left"></i>
 </button>
</form>
```

There are a lot of other codes in between the form. Other button with their own formaction.
The issue is, the Accept button click trigger AccPay/SavePay instead of AccPay/AcceptPay

Here's the js code for onclick event checkDateValidation1

```
function checkDateValidation1(redirect) {
    debugger;
    
    //some code
    if (somecondition) {
        openConfirmationModal()
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

//opens the confirmation model
function openConfirmationModal(isPast) {
    if (isPast) $("#confirmationModal p:first").text(PAST_INVOICEDATE_MESSAGE)
    else $("#confirmationModal p:first").text(FUTURE_INVOICEDATE_MESSAGE)
    $('#confirmationModal').openModal({ dismissable: false });
}

$("#confirmInvoiceDateButton1").on('click', function () {
   return true;
})

$("#cancelInvoiceDateButton").on('click', function () {
    return false;
})
```

How do I make the code make call to AcceptPay instead of SavePay?

EDIT:
If i have no onCLick event it works perfectly fine, the action to AcceptPay is triggered as expected.

Comment: You return false on the button, that might cancel the button action? What happens if you remove all script from the button and just have the form with save and the button with accept

Comment: removing onclick works as expected